# Using a constant tone to find the key center

Tags: key, analysis

I have a song that I'm trying to figure out the key center. I'll explain the process and you can tell me if I"m on the right track. 
I start by analyzing the song using software that finds the chords. (Studio One ) . I know that this is not an exact science even with modern software. It shows the main chords being F-G and D and seventh variations of those including major and minor G's. So that didnt help me since it doesnt seem to fit a progression I would expect from a New Orleans blues, slide song.
Next I play the song and hold down various keys and find the one that sounds like it could be the key center. This seemed to work the best as I can just let this tone play for as long as I want, through the main sections, chorus solos...
So the D sounds best by far, but I want to be sure I'm right and at this point and I'm not good enough to figure out the progression manually in a timely manner.
My question is, is playing the note like I do a acceptable way of finding the key center and how would the three main chords of D,F and G fit into a common progression ?
Thanks

Comment: It's better to home in on cadence points and find the chord there.

Comment: Have you ever found or suspected that the key center of the chorus is different from the key center of the verses?

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to find the key center? Who or what is supposed to do what, with the key center information?

Comment: piiperi...knowing the key center helps you in your overall knowledge of the song. It also along with other information, makes it easier to transcribe a piece.

Comment: @mike628 So are you trying to transcribe a song, to make a lead sheet for a band, and you'd like to write correct key signatures? Or you'd like to know what the key is, so you could better guess what the chords are? Why not ask how to find the key of a passage of music? It could be that the effective key center changes throughout the song. Does the song have a melody? How about transcribing the melody first? Can you play even parts of the melody by ear? If you are sure about the bass notes and the melody notes, then you're already quite far in getting it transcribed.

Comment: @piiperi, I can answer most of those questions as yes, but I think you misunderstand the question or I explained it in too much detail. The reason I want to know is irrelevant. Here it is simplified : Can you find the key center of a passage by playing a drone over that section ?

Comment: I think there are much easier and more certain ways for finding the key center for a passage of music than playing a constant tone over an entire passage.

Comment: So, tell us what they are?

Comment: @Laurence I think there are already several questions and answers about that, and I don't feel inspired to re-write about that here to a person who seems to be relying on some piece of software for listing chords, instead of, say, finding bass notes and melody notes, and trying to play other notes on top of those to get a feel of possible scales or cadences or anything. He seems to have decided that this "software and constant drone sound" method must be the way to go, and answers must be about that exact method only. I addressed that method only. Boxing day football feels more interesting.

Comment: @piiperi I didn't say or imply I was using software to find the key center, just as an added tool to possibly help me decide if I was on the right path. I can transcribe melodies quite well, chords not so quickly. And as far as "decided" , actually just the opposite, hence the reason for even asking in the first place. I understand harmonic analysis is about listening and figuring it all out, but when you're new at all of this, everything that can confirm or deny your intuition helps the learning process.  Understanding?

Comment: The "one single steady pitch for a long time" idea doesn't feel suitable for finding the key. Find bass notes, melody notes and see what scale they seem to fit. Make a guess and play a so-fa-mi-re-do line in your guessed key. Does the final "do" feel like you landed home and that could be the end of the song? If not, make a new guess and try again. Pause the song, can you play I - IV - V - I in the guessed key and the "I" feels like a "I" in the song? If not, guess again. Anyway, forget the "one long drone" idea and read up on learning to find the key.

Comment: Thanks @piiperi,  that's the constructive answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

When a chord appears in both major and minor forms, consider the possibility that it's IV.

But I have to say, if you need software assistance in finding the chords, you're probably not ready to do much harmonic analysis.  Work on detecting what the notes and chords ARE.  Hanging a key label on them isn't really that important, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Using that constant tone is certaintly a valid way to determine the key, but I think there are better ways. For starters, using harmonic analysis software, as you have wisely noted, is dodgy at best, impossible at worst. Especially with blues and other non-diatonic progressions, software can't tell the context well enough to put good chord labels on them. But I think the best solution would be to develop a better musical ear so that you could tell "oh, this song is centered on this". It sounds like you're nearly there, so don't despair! And yes, eventually you do need some reference tone to identify "oh, the note the song centers on, that's an E♭ on my (musical instrument)" (I must sound like a broken record, but that isn't necessary if you have perfect pitch).